# 2 way crypt image filename

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt, php-openssl

I would like to change an image filename with a crypted string.

I need also:

- Crypting more multiple time the original string with the same password, will return the same string
- The encrypted string should be decrypted (2 way crypt)

What php method could I use?
I saw that mcrypt is not updated from lots of years, and openssl_crypt will return different encrypted strings each time I encrypt (even if the password is the same).

Thanks

Comment: [Why?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#66378)

Comment: @Sammitch in order to create a unique filename based upon variable params passed to the method that will generate the image (like height, width and so on)

Comment: You could call the file like "myimage_200_400_stretched.jpg".
A one way non-authenticated hash like sha256 is also often used for caching files, most systems don't need 2-way nor authentication.

Comment: You should go back a step and re-evaluate the problem you're trying to solve with this, because the solution is ridiculous.

Comment: @Sammitch you are free to propose a solution

Comment: I get that you want unique, descriptive filenames, but you've yet to adequately explain how or why two-way encryption is necessary.

Comment: In order to not display the parameters added to the unique filename. The not-encrypted filename should contain something like height, width and other useful information used for post-processing. I started a repo about it, you can see the doc: https://github.com/pensiero/image-uploader

Comment: PS: why I don't want to display the parameters in the filename? because I don't want anybody to freely change them, because if you change it, it will be done a resize (and this could be used to flood the server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openssl_encrypt & co should be fine. example:

```
<?php
$data='foo.jpg';
$method='AES-192-CBC';
$password='ogiughjklpdeorivjrhfnd';
$iv=base64_encode(random_bytes(10));
$encrypted=array();
for($i=0;$i<10;++$i){
    $encrypted[]=openssl_encrypt($data,$method,$password,0,$iv );
}
$decrypted=openssl_decrypt ($encrypted[0] ,$method ,$password,0,$iv);

var_dump($data,$encrypted[0],$decrypted,$data===$decrypted,$encrypted[2]===$encrypted[7],$encrypted);
```

quote `openssl_crypt will return different encrypted strings each time I encrypt (even if the password is the same).` - not with AES-192-CBC, as long as the password AND IV is identical. i think that's why IV's was invented in the first place, to prevent the same data to encrypt to the exact same encrypted form

Comment: Technically you've provided a solution but reusing IV's breaks the security of most systems.

Comment: @ErikvanVelzen yeah, but i believe that proper use of unique IVs are fundamentally incompatible with the requirement that `encrypting the exact same data twice should yield the exact same output` - that is exactly what IV's are supposed to prevent

Comment: Why are you taking random bytes, the things that IVs are made of, and base64'ing them? Why are you using AES-192? How do you have such a fundamental misunderstanding of what IVs are?

Comment: @Sammitch base64 encoding the IV because binary data (or, specifically, NULL bytes) causes issues in PHP when debugging (for example, PHP's error logging and Exception::__construct's $message is not binary safe, if an exception is thrown that includes a binary $iv in the call stack's argument dump, the error log will stop at the first NULL byte), its probably the same reason that openssl_encrypt returns base64'ed data by default. i'm using AES for no particular reason, it's just a very popular algorithm. PS, base64 encoding the IV is a very common practice. see  Linux/BSD/crypt/password_hash

Answer (score 0):

You should use a block cipher.

I'd suggest Zend\Crypt\BlockCipher or \Sodium\crypto_secretbox

Both are easy to use correctly and have clear documentation.

And openssl_crypt returning different strings with the same data is necessary for security. Both methods above will do the same.

Comment: Thanks @Erik, I will try them

Comment: and none of your 3 suggestions meets the requirements with proper use of IVs. face it, you HAVE to re-use IV's on this one.